# NPM build with webpack not working in Docker file

Tags: docker, npm, webpack

My webpack build works fine when i run npm run build in my local. But fails when execute `docker build` with the below error

```
    #0 3.075 ERROR in main
    #0 3.075 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/abc'
    #0 3.075 resolve './src' in '/abc'
    #0 3.075   using description file: /abc/package.json (relative path: .).
```

Below is my docker code

```
FROM node18_image

WORKDIR /abc

# When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /
COPY .npmrc package*.json ./src/ ./

RUN npm install

COPY src/ ./src
COPY tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json

RUN npm run build
```

Below is my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ts'),
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin'),
  },
};
```

I am not sure where its failing, I have used copy src as well. Since I am new to Docker I am not sure why its failing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed That you are trying to copy `package.json` file and `.npmrc` file into the `./src/` directory before you even copy the dir it self ?

Changing the order should resolve this error.

the file should look like this :

```
FROM node18_image

WORKDIR /abc
COPY src/ ./src
COPY .npmrc package*.json ./src/ ./

RUN npm install


COPY tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json

RUN npm run build
```

Comment: No, it didn't. facing the same issue